# HeatmapLayer gradient fades when zooming

Tags: google-maps-api-3, opacity, heatmap

Problem:
When zooming a heat map the gradient gets to thin (dillutedt) to be visible.

(google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer)

I have set

```
            heatmap.setOptions({

                //radius: 10,

                opacity: 1.0,

                //dissipating: false
            });
```

to no avail.

I have experienced with radius and dissipating, no success.

Answer (score 16):

For those reading this, here is the solution:

```
            heatmap.setOptions({
                dissipating: true,
                maxIntensity: 10,
                radius: 5,
                opacity: 0.9,
                //dissipating: false
            });
```